# Uniqueness theorem for ODE $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ under the assumption $\langle f(t,y)-f(t,z),y-z\rangle\le l(t)|y-z|^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why the inequality; $\langle f(t,y)-f(t,z),y-z\rangle\le l(t)|y-z|^2$ implies that the Cauchy problem $\begin{cases} y'(t)=f(t,y(t))\\  y(t_0)=y_0 \end{cases}$ has a unique solution ?

Actually the inequality looks like the Lipschitz condition, I can show that the solution exists for all time, but there is a small problem in the line with $(\star)$ because we assume that $y(t_0)=z(t_0)=y_0$, so there is a division by zero.

$\langle f(t,y)-f(t,z),y-z\rangle\le l(t)|y-z|^2$

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\left(|y(t)-z(t)|^2\right)\le 2l(t)|y(t)-z(t)|^2$

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\log\left(|y(t)-z(t)|^2\right)\le2l(t)$

$\displaystyle\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{d}{ds}\log\left(|y(s)-z(s)|^2\right)ds\le2\int_{t_0}^{t}l(s)ds$

$\log\left(\frac{|y(s)-z(s)|^2}{|y(t_0)-z(t_0)|}\right)\le...$$(\bigstar)$

$\displaystyle |y(t)-z(t)|^2\le|y(t_1)-z(t_1)|e^{2\int_{t_0}^tl(s)ds}$

Also to apply the following argument with $\varphi$ (for the uniqueness), must $l$ be not necessarily positive ?

[image]

because I get $\varphi'(t)\le -l(t)e^{-2L(t)}|y-z|^2\le 0\iff l(t)\ge 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we should assume $l(t)\ge 0$, which is not a restriction at all: if the inequality $\langle f(t,y)-f(t,z),y-z\rangle\le l(t)|y-z|^2$ holds for some $l\in L^1$, it also holds for $\langle f(t,y)-f(t,z),y-z\rangle\le l^+(t)|y-z|^2$ where $l^+(t)=\max(l(t),0)$.

Concerning the proof: In order to talk about $\displaystyle \log\left(|y(t)-z(t)|^2\right)\le2l(t)$ we must assume $y(t)\ne z(t)$ on some interval, that is, the uniqueness fails. Typically, one takes a connected component of the set $\{t:y(t)\ne z(t)\}$, which is an interval, and denotes by $t_0$ the left endpoint of this interval. Then the computations go almost as above. On the line 
$$\displaystyle\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{d}{ds}\log\left(|y(s)-z(s)|^2\right)ds\le2\int_{t_0}^{t}l(s)ds$$
the integrals should be inderstood in the improper sense. That is, they are actually limits of 
$$\displaystyle\int_{t_1}^{t}\frac{d}{ds}\log\left(|y(s)-z(s)|^2\right)ds\le2\int_{t_1}^{t}l(s)ds$$
as $t_1$ approaches $ t_0 $ from the right. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, 
$$\log\left(\frac{|y(s)-z(s)|^2}{|y(t_1)-z(t_1)|}\right)\le 2\int_{t_1}^{t}l(s)ds$$ Letting $t_1\to t_0$ yields a contradiction: the left side tends to $\infty$, the right side has a finite limit.